# MYSQL: Partitioning Table keeping id unique

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

We are using a table which has schema like following:-

```
CREATE TABLE `user_subscription` (
`ID` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`COL1` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`COL2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`COL3` datetime NOT NULL,
`COL4` datetime NOT NULL,
`ARCHIVE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Now we wanted to do partition on column ARCHIVE. ARCHIVE can have only 2 values 0 or 1 and so 2 partitions.

Actually in our case, we are using partitioning as a Archival process. To do partition, we need to make ARCHIVE column as a part of primary key. But the problem here is that 2 rows can have same ID with different ARCHIVE column value. Actually thats not the main problem for us as 2 rows will be in different partitions. Problem is when we will update the archive column value of one of them to other to move one of the row to archive partition, then it will not allow us to update the entry giving "Duplicate Error".

Can somebody help in this regard?

Comment: why would your `id` be getting duplicated?

Comment: @pala_ because id and archive have to be primary key combined for partitioning to work and hence id can be duplicated for different archive column values 0 and 1.

Comment: ... you can still have a unique index on id by itself

Comment: @pala_ if I am adding unique constraint on id, then I am getting error that partition column should also be part of Unique index. So, it also cannot help me ...

Comment: ah. then you'll need to use a sequence table to generate the ids. you can use a `before insert` trigger to add it in automatically

Comment: What is `id`?  It is longer than normal UUIDs/GUIDs.  Is it the only way you access rows?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,

> A `UNIQUE INDEX` (or a `PRIMARY KEY`) must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

and since MySQL does not support check constraints either, the only ugly workaround I can think of is enforcing the uniqueness manually though triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  archived TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, archived),  -- required by MySQL limitation on partitioning
)
PARTITION BY LIST(archived) (
  PARTITION pActive VALUES IN (0),
  PARTITION pArchived VALUES IN (1)
);

CREATE TRIGGER tInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON t FOR EACH ROW
CALL checkUnique(NEW.id);

CREATE TRIGGER tUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE ON t FOR EACH ROW
CALL checkUnique(NEW.id);

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE checkUnique(pId INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE flag INT;
  DECLARE message VARCHAR(50);
  SELECT id INTO flag FROM t WHERE id = pId;
  IF flag IS NOT NULL THEN
    -- the below tries to mimic the error raised
    -- by a regular UNIQUE constraint violation
    SET message = CONCAT("Duplicate entry '", pId, "'");
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE "23000" SET
      MYSQL_ERRNO = 1062,
      MESSAGE_TEXT = message,
      COLUMN_NAME = "id";
  END IF;
END //
```

([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0270c))

[MySQL's limitations on partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html) being such a downer (in particular its lack of support for foreign keys), I would advise against using it altogether until the table grows so large that it becomes an actual concern.